# Thumbnails Slider in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make Bootstrap 3 thumbnails slider like below image which slides the thumbs one by one. As you already know there some sample on the web like [this one](http://www.bootply.com/81478) which is using Bootstrap Carousel and is doing BOX sliding (sliding several thumbs on one click). But I need to slide the thumbs one by one.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See this example..

http://bootply.com/94452

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
```

It requires some custom positioning on the carousel items, and jQuery to load the active items into the carousel.

Comment: Great thanks Baghoo, this is awesome, just can you also let me know how I can stop Infinite looping and stop slider when reaches the last child? or first child from left? Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of displaying one image at a time and you are able to scroll them one by one.

```
            <div id="carousel-home-one" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-home-one" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-home-one" data-slide-to="1"></li>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" style="background-color: #737373;">
              <div class="item active"><img src="imageonehere.jpg" alt="one" />
              </div>
                <div class="item"><img src="nextimagehere.jpg" alt="two" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-home-one" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-home-one" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi Skewled , thanks for reply but this code is not out putting anything! did you had a chance to test it already? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's only a matter of changing your grid classes.

Within the `.item .row`, specify the number of images to be placed with the grid classes adjusted.

<kbd>[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/130706)</kbd>

The structure should look like:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Carousel items -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
         <div class="row">
            <!-- specify number of images by changing this grid class -->
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!--/row-->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!--/row-->
      </div>
      <!--/item-->
   </div>
   <!--/carousel-inner--><a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
<!--/myCarousel-->
```